# Handle large kusto data in c#

Tags: c#, .net, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I am currently working on a C# project, that reads and stores very large amount of records from a kusto table.
I am thinking of doing pagination for reading the data.
Please suggest some programming techniques to handle(read and store) such huge tables.
(Basically I am storing each row as an object).

Comment: **(1)** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/stored-query-results **(2)** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/continuous-data-export

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [stored query results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/stored-query-results) if you want to freeze the data while you page it,or can use the [take operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/take-operator#paging-of-query-results) to page through them (but they might change if new data gets added). You do need to be able to sort them consistently for this to work.